# Trying to load js files in my website

Tags: javascript, web, assets

I'm trying to load the `js` files inside the directory `/public_html/javascript/` but it gives a 404 error, i checked the permissions of the directory and files and it seems to be all right. I have another directory `css/` inside with the same permissions and i dont have problems to load the files inside, any help?

Comment: 404 means "not found" not "permission denied".

Comment: try ./public_html/javascript/

Comment: @karaxuna yesss it says "Forbidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 means file not found. 403 would be more related to permissions.

I would start by using web developer tools (e.g. Firebug, etc), which should give you the url of the javascript file that is being requested by the browser, that should make it easier to verify the path, and modify accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Firebug. I don't have any problem to go to `contractlink.local/css` , and the permissions are the same as in `contraclink.local/javascript` (drwxr-xr-x ) so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `conf.d` folder in apache and in there there is a file called `javascript-common.conf` Inside there is an alias `javascript` to `/usr/share/javascript/`. I commented it, i restart apache and now the javascript folder is not forbidden any more.